# Trying to find a match within multiple lines with help of a regex

Tags: c#, regex

This might be a simple question for quite a lot of people, but it still is a puzzle to me (perhaps as I am a complete n00b on regular expressions).

I am working to find a regular expression that might help find mistakes in huge files of logging information.

Basically, I need to find a number, always starting with a Z, followed by exactly 11 digits. Consider Z00000012345 as an example.

This number is used in multiple sentences, example given:

> Line 144: 07:16:36:933 | Important event received: number arrived:
>   Z00000012345
>   Line 162: 07:16:42:314 | Processing  and doing extremely
>   important stuff...
>   Line 164: 07:16:42:374 | Almost ready with processing number Z00000012345
>   Line 165: 07:16:42:374 | Success with processing; number 'Z00000012345' has been processed.

**What do I need to find:**
It sometimes occurs that the number that has been processed (the number between single quotes), differs from the number that has arrived at the system (first line).

The other tricky thing is that there is not an exact amount of fixed sentences in between.

I would like to have it setup in groups, as that comparison might then be the most easy one, so I started with:

```
(?<Found>(\barrived:\s)(\w+))
```

My goal was to capture the word just behind 'arrived:' first and then find the next group that matches the same word but then between single quotes (as seen in the last line).

However, how can I do that easily?
Ultimately, I would like to bring this into a C# tool.

By the way, the files run up to 8 gigabytes in size, hence the way I am looking for speed.

**Desired output:**
The desired output is a flag whenever there is **no** match between the first number (see line 144 in the example) and the final number on line 165. If these are wrong, I have a mismatch. As this is very very rare, I thought that it would be best to search it that way.

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/lq6SYE/1

Comment: Almost, that regex gives all pairs of the same number, where I am only interested in the first and last. All between need to be ignored... So it is a fact that the last number is always between single quotes...

Comment: You will have to regex each line to see if there is a number, so a simple distinct at the end, may be enought performance wise.

Comment: This should work: https://regex101.com/r/j7rFwY/1
Regex : [Z]\d{11}

Comment: For the speed i will say : 
FileStream File.Open > BufferedStream > StreamReader > while ReadLine() != null > add the match in a hashset. This way no duplicate, no memory over flow. as fast as you can read.

Comment: @RvdV79 the solution from xdTransoform works fine for me, what should be the output ? Z00000012345 ?

Comment: @Bob the solutions work indeed, but let me update the question. As the output I need is a statement of True or False whenever the first number is not exactly the same as the final one between the single quotes.

Comment: @RvdV79 yea you should update the question.

Comment: you need some thing like this https://regex101.com/r/DDYsCw/1?

Comment: My bad I thought you where looking for every instance of Z-word. And not for the diffrences between arrived and handled.  What about making a list of arrived and processed and  Exclude do see with number is not processed yet? Does that sound like a reasonable solution to the general issue?

Comment: That indeed sounds like the thing that I need, can that also be handled with a single regex?

Comment: In a one liner: no. I will recommend going for BufferedStream  and apply 2 regex twice for readability. Or I will go like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/bnYsmQ. `Disclaimer typed on a tablet. the commented code my not compile`. No bechmarck done to see if 2 regex are faster than one with 2 group. And first group may be edited to get only the arrived line.

Comment: In this code the hashset may be to big. Perhaps processed result will be removed from created listif they exist or add into a created out of fine air hashset if they do not match an existing number. This way instead of having Really big Hashset the size reduce at every matching pair. It's always the balance between memory and computation.

Comment: This - `(?m)\barrived:\s*(Z[0-9]{11})\r?$(?>\r?\n(?!.*\barrived:\s*Z\d{11}).*)*\r?\n.*number\s+'\1'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lq6SYE/3))? Or this - `(?m)\barrived:\s*(Z[0-9]{11})\r?$(?>\r?\n(?!.*\barrived:\s*Z\d{11}).*)*\r?\n.*number\s+'(?!\1')Z\d{11}'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lq6SYE/2))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
arrived:\s*(Z\d{11})((?!arrived)[\s\S])*'((?:(?!\1)[^'])+)'
```

This is demo:
https://regex101.com/r/RAI4Zh/1

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just use this pattern and make sure you use the RegexOptions.Compiled for speed and RegexOptions.MultiLine for capturing multiline.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string logFileContent = "Line 144: 07:16:36:933 | Important event received: number arrived: Z00000012345\r\nLine 162: 07:16:42:314 | Processing and doing extremely important stuff...\r\nLine 164: 07:16:42:374 | Almost ready with processing number Z00000012345\r\nLine 165: 07:16:42:374 | Success with processing; number 'Z00000012345' has been processed.\r\n";

string pattern = @"(?<WholeMatch>\'?(?<Number>Z\d{11})\'?)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(logFileContent, pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Of course you can modify the pattern above for speed or just use as simple as this

```
string pattern = @"\'?(Z\d{11})\'?";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I did not entirely ask for this approach. This would capture all matches and numbers, whereas I need to find a match between only the first line (144) and the last line (165). If these are ok, then I need to do nothing, but if they are wrong, I need to list that.

Comment: oh i see. if i'm not mistaken, you just want to find the match of the id that preceeded by "arrived:" and then 'id'. is that correct?